# Задача "Интересное путешествие" от Яндекса, не проходит тест

Tags: python

16 тестов проходит, на 17м фейлится, в чем проблема, понять не могу. Какое там может быть такое граничное условие, которое может не пройти... Делаю словарь из городов и их координат. Затем рекурсивно как бы строю граф, пока не встречу конечный город и выведу подсчитанное кол-во городов на пути.

UPD. Немного уменьшил код, но рекурсивным он так и остался.

UPD2. Все прошло.

**G. Интересное путешествие**

Ограничение времени 1 секунда

Ограничение памяти 64Mb

Ввод стандартный ввод или input.txt

Вывод стандартный вывод или output.txt

Не секрет, что некоторые программисты очень любят путешествовать. Хорошо всем известный программист Петя тоже очень любит путешествовать, посещать музеи и осматривать достопримечательности других городов.

Для перемещений между из города в город он предпочитает использовать машину. При этом он заправляется только на станциях в городах, но не на станциях по пути. Поэтому он очень аккуратно выбирает маршруты, чтобы машина не заглохла в дороге. А ещё Петя очень важный член команды, поэтому он не может себе позволить путешествовать слишком долго. Он решил написать программу, которая поможет ему с выбором очередного путешествия. Но так как сейчас у него слишком много других задач, он попросил вас помочь ему.

Расстояние между двумя городами считается как сумма модулей разности по каждой из координат. Дороги есть между всеми парами городов.

**Формат ввода**

В первой строке входных данных записано количество городов n (2≤n≤1000). В следующих n строках даны два целых числа: координаты каждого города, не превосходящие по модулю миллиарда. Все города пронумерованы числами от 1 до n в порядке записи во входных данных.

В следующей строке записано целое положительное число k, не превосходящее двух миллиардов, — максимальное расстояние между городами, которое Петя может преодолеть без дозаправки машины.

В последней строке записаны два различных числа — номер города, откуда едет Петя, и номер города, куда он едет.

**Формат вывода**

Если существуют пути, удовлетворяющие описанным выше условиям, то выведите минимальное количество дорог, которое нужно проехать, чтобы попасть из начальной точки маршрута в конечную. Если пути не существует, выведите -1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
from collections import deque

n = int(input())

cities = {}

for i in range(1, n + 1):
cities[i] = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

without_oil = int(input())

current_city, end_city = [int(x) for x in input().split()]


def finder():
if current_city == end_city:
    return 0
search_queue = deque()
search_queue += [(key, 0) for key, value in cities.items()
                 if abs(value[0] - cities[current_city][0]) +
                 abs(value[1] - cities[current_city][1]) <= without_oil
                 and key != current_city]
searched = [current_city, ]
while search_queue:
    city = search_queue.popleft()
    if not city[0] in searched:
        searched.append(city[0])
        if city[0] == end_city:
            return city[1] + 1
        else:
            search_queue += [(key, city[1] + 1) for key, value in cities.items()
                             if abs(value[0] - cities[city[0]][0]) +
                             abs(value[1] - cities[city[0]][1]) <= without_oil
                             and key not in searched]
return -1


print(finder())
```

Comment: `counter is not None`. Все операторы `return` возвращают числа. Получается что вы возвращаете иногда `-1` даже если решение есть.

Comment: Рекурсия в Питоне может быть ограничена глубиной в тысячу. У вас рекурсивный поиск на тысячу городов. Надо  писать без рекурсии.

Comment: Копировать список посещённых городов не нужно. Не пройдёте по времени.

Comment: Отыщите вариант не рекурсивного обхода графа с использованием `stack` и `visited`.

Comment: Так у меня даже и графа толком нет, я его получается через рекурсию одновременно строю и обхожу

Comment: Сделал через очередь, теперь ловлю на 18м Time-Limit

Comment: Ссылку на задачу дайте.

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете евклидову метрику (обычное расстояние по прямой) для расстояния между городами,

```
 cur_path = sqrt((value[0] - cities[current_city][0]) ** 2 + (value[1] - cities[current_city][1]) ** 2)
```

в то время как в задаче требуется манхэттенское расстояние `Расстояние между двумя городами считается как сумма модулей разности по каждой из координат`:

```
cur_path=abs(value[0]-cities[current_city][0])+abs(value[1]-cities[current_city][1])
```

Comment: Заменил, теперь вообще зафейлилось на 15м тесте)

Comment: Ну я привел самое очевидное нарушение. Вам нужна аккуратная реализация BFS с очередью

Comment: Сделал через очередь, теперь ловлю на 18м Time-Limit